# Get the actual Qt window title, properly replacing the [*] placeholder

Tags: qt, pyqt, titlebar

I need to get the *visible* title of a Qt top level window (or MDI subwindow), because I want to list window titles in different places just like they're visible for the user.

Consider a program that supports multiple top level editor windows (or an MDI area with similar purposes) that should list the titles of those windows, like a menu or an internal "window manager".

If I want to list those windows and also support the `[*]` placeholder for the [`windowModified`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowModified-prop) property, their `windowTitle()` will return that annoying placeholder no matter of their state.

Unfortunately, the [`windowTitle`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowTitle-prop) feature is a bit abstract, for the following reasons:

- due to the `windowModified` feature, it always returns the placeholder if it's set;
- the `[*]` placeholder can be "escaped" with multiple, *even* occurrences, in order to actually display `[*]` in the window title: `Title [*][*]` will always be shown as `Title [*]` no matter the value of the `windowModified` property;
- if the `windowTitle` property is an empty string (the default), it falls back to the [`windowFilePath`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowFilePath-prop) property, which not only make it **always** include the `[*]` placeholder, but could also behave oddly in the rare case that property contains the `[*]` placeholder; while I realize that this is a very odd (and somehow irresponsible, assuming the system actually supports it) situation, I still want a reliable way to get the currently resulting window title, even in those rare (though "wrong") situations;

Is there a way to get the *real* title that Qt sets for the window, considering the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no absolute and certain way to get the title that the OS will *finally* show in the title bar of a top level window.

As explained in the [`windowTitle`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowTitle-prop) documentation, some systems might support displaying the [`applicationDisplayName`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#applicationDisplayName-prop). Some highly customizable (Linux) OS might show an altered version of the provided title. There is almost no way to get the "final", displayed title, unless you want to dig into specific OS modules that interface with the Window Manager (and that might not be enough anyway, due to the high level of customization possible on *nix systems).

Considering that what's relevant for the OP is the "internal" window title (what Qt finally "relays" to the system), the solution is to implement what Qt actually does internally with [`qt_setWindowTitle_helperHelper()`](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/kernel/qwidget.cpp?h=5.15.2#n5822).

Be aware that the Qt implementation is *not* perfect. There are some odd cases when specific combinations of the placeholder string are used. For instance:

- using `[*] [*] [*]` as window title results in "`[*]`" being shown for an unmodified window and "`* [*] *`" otherwise;
- with `[*] [*][*] [*]`, the unmodified window title is " `[*] [*]`" (note the leading space) and the other is "`* [*]* [*]`"

While, as said above, the Qt implementation is far from perfect, what we're interested into is the *actual* window title relayed to the OS, so we must adhere to it, since the *visual* result is the important aspect, no matter whether it's "correct" or not.

Finally, remember that this implementation might become invalid in the future, in case Qt developers decide to change this behavior (and, I believe, they should).

The following code is a simple function that will return the *actual* window title relayed to the OS for a give widget, which can be used for any situation in which the *visible* title has to be displayed:

```py
def realWindowTitle(widget):
    title = widget.windowTitle()
    placeHolder = '[*]'
    if not placeHolder in title:
        return title
    phSize = len(placeHolder)

    style = widget.style()
    if (widget.isWindowModified()
        and style.styleHint(
            style.SH_TitleBar_ModifyNotification, None, widget)
            # for PyQt6 or full Enum support use
            # style.StyleHint.SH_TitleBar_ModifyNotification
        ):
            replaceHolder = '*'
    else:
        replaceHolder = ''

    index = title.find(placeHolder)
    while index != -1:
        index += phSize
        count = 1

        while title.find(placeHolder, index) == index:
            count += 1
            index += phSize

        if count % 2: # odd number of [*] -> replace last one
            lastIndex = title.rfind(placeHolder, 0, index)
            title = (title[:lastIndex] 
                + replaceHolder 
                + title[lastIndex + phSize:])

        index = title.find(placeHolder, index)

    # return "escaped" sequences of the remaining double placeholders
    return title.replace('[*][*]', placeHolder)
```

Answer (score 1):

The best approach for top level windows (not MDI subwindows) is to use [`QWindow::title`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwindow.html#title-prop):

> This property holds the window's title in the windowing system
>
> The window title might appear in the title area of the window
> decorations, depending on the windowing system and the window flags.
> It might also be used by the windowing system to identify the window
> in other contexts, such as in the task switcher.

**How to obtain the `QWindow`?**

If you already know the `QWidget`, you can use [`QWidget::windowHandle`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#window). Note that the `QWindow` object is only available for native widgets (f.ex. top level widgets, but not for MDI subwindow).

Another approach is to directly query for all the top level windows using [`QGuiApplication::topLevelWindows`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qguiapplication.html#topLevelWindows)

**MDI subwindow support?**

As those MDI subwindows are not top level windows, the `QWindow` doesn't exists. So, this approach doesn't work in that case. Possible solutions are:

- See @musicamente's answer, mimicking the Qt placeholder replacement procedure.
- Create a [Qt bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io) to expose the resolved window title or alter the Qt source code yourself to do so and distribute it with your application.

Comment: The idea of using QWindow is clever, kudos for that. Unfortunately, it only works for top level windows, but not for child windows (like MDI subwindows), because the private `setWindowTitle_helper()` updates the QWindow title only when the widget has the `Window` flag: the result is that it properly updates the QWindow title when the widget instance is created without any parent (and `self.winId()` is called), but as soon as it's reparented, the QWindow title is not updated anymore not only for the `setWindowModified()`, but even for any `setWindowTitle()` calls.

Comment: @musicamante Yes, I know. I updated the answer to make it more clear it only works for top level windows.